# Unable to connect to mariadb database server with qt 4.8.5 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, qt, ubuntu, mariadb

I use the following code to connect to a MySQL server database.

```
QSqlDatabase db_Server = QSqlDatabase::database("Test");

//find mysql driver
db_Server = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","Test");
db_Server.setHostName("188.**.***.***");
db_Server.setPort(3306);
db_Server.setDatabaseName("Test");
db_Server.setUserName("Test");
db_Server.setPassword("*********");

bool ret = db_Server.open();
if(ret) qDebug() << "Database open"
else qDebug() << db_Server.lastError().text();
```

Lately they changed the server to mariadb and I assumed it was compatible with QMYSQL driver and used the above code to access the database, but I get the following error
"Can't connect to MySQL server on '188.**.***.***' (101) QMYSQL: Unable to connect"

Is there any additional thing that I need to do with mariadb to connect to the server? Any help is appreciated

I had built the MySQL plugin the following way

```
#sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
#cd $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqdrivers/mysql
#sudo qmake “INCLUDEPATH+=usr/include/mysql” “LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu –lmysqlclient_r” mysql.pro
#sudo make
#sudo make install
```

Should I do any changes for mariadb similarly?

Comment: I assume the *** is to make it anonymous and you're using the proper IP address in the actual code? Did you try with the mysql command line client on the same host?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld It was a problem with the database and not the Qt application, the connection refused if a password was used. I had tried connecting using mysql workbench and it worked fine, so I didn't know there was a password related issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the database and not the Qt application, the connection refused if a password was used.